# Is there any interaction between hypothetical continuous effects?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Consider a battlefield where I control a [Deadfall](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Deadfall), a [Sunweb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sunweb), and a [Muraganda Petroglyphs](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Muraganda%20Petroglyphs). Importantly, Sunweb says

> Sunweb can't block creatures with power 2 or less.

Deadfall says

> Creatures with forestwalk can be blocked **as though they didn't have forestwalk**.

and Muraganda Petroglyphs says

> Creatures with no abilities get +2/+2.

If my opponent attacks with a [Jukai Messenger](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jukai%20Messenger) (a 1/1 Forestwalk creature), can my Sunweb block it?

The answer seems at first to be "no", but if the Messenger didn't have forestwalk, it wouldn't have any abilities, so it would get +2/+2 due to Muraganda Petroglyphs' ability, which would make it big enough for Sunweb to block. So the question is really:

When declaring blockers (or checking whether a declaration is legal) and Deadfall is in play and you choose to block as though the creature didn't have forestwalk, are other continuous effects also applied as though the creature didn't have forestwalk?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Sunweb can't block the Jukai Messenger.

There's a bit of confusion here about the scope of "as though". It definitely only applies to the stated situation ("...can be blocked..."), but

> 613.10. Some continuous effects affect game rules rather than objects. For example, effects may modify a player’s maximum hand size, or say that a creature must attack this turn if able. ***These effects are applied after all other continuous effects have been applied.*** Continuous effects that affect the costs of spells or abilities are applied according to the order specified in rule 601.2e. All other such effects are applied in timestamp order. See also the rules for timestamp order and dependency (rules 613.6 and 613.7).

Muraganda Petroglyph's effect is a power/toughness changing ability, so it's applied first (in layer 7). The Messenger has an ability, so it stays a 1/1.

Deadfall's effect modifies game rules (changing the way blocking works), so it is applied *last*. (Ability-removing effects do get applied earlier on, but this is not an ability-removing effect - the creature never loses forestwalk.)

So when deciding whether Sunweb can block, we have a 1/1 Messenger with forestwalk (which is non-functional, thanks to Deadfall). Sunweb therefore can't block it, since its power is 2 or less.

---

There was also some question about the scope of "as though" in this case. One possibility is that it applies *only* to the blocking legality decision itself, and thus it doesn't interact with the other effects. Another is that it applies to the whole game state at the time that blocking legality is decided, in which case if it were to apply before the other effects, it would change the outcome. It's difficult to tell for sure which of these is correct; the rules don't go so far as defining "can be blocked as though". But since according to 613.10, it's applied last, we don't have to worry about any of that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14026/discussion-between-jefromi-and-ikegami)

Comment: I was almost tempted to post this as a separate answer, but I don't feel like rewriting most of what you wrote just to add it. Rule 101.1 reads, **"Whenever a card’s text directly contradicts these rules, the card takes precedence. The card  overrides only the rule that applies to that specific situation."** Does it override the rules concerning blockers? *Yes*, because it *says so on the card*. Does it override any other rules? *No.* It's really not any more complicated than that.

Comment: @Rusher Yup, similar to the "as though" rule, edited in. I do think, though, that the OP was originallyunsure exactly what situation "can be blocked" referred to - is it just the blocking decision itself, or is it the entire state of the game while you're making that decision?

Comment: @Jefromi Revisiting this question/answer, I just want to say that I originally accepted this answer because of the reference to rule 613. I'm really not sure why you removed it, because it's the only convincing argument I've seen across both answers. I don't think 101.1 applies because the question is about the interaction between two abilities in the context of the same situation: declaring blockers and determining constraints for that declaration. In my mind, that makes the entire second half of the answer irrelevant because the question *is* about declaring blockers.

Comment: I have downvoted this answer because even though the conclusion is correct, the explanation is incomplete at best. The primary reasoning is that Deadfall's ability is only relevant to determining whether blocks are legal, which **completely** ignores the fact that the question specifically asks about the result of interactions when determining whether blocks are legal. And second, the single referenced rule can be interpreted to support either conclusion, depending on how you interpret the scope of "stated effect". Only rule 613.10 unambiguously answers this question.

Comment: @murgatroid If there's a revision you like, please just roll it back, otherwise I'll try to come back later and sort out what happened here. (I'm pretty sure other people were not happy with the part I took out, and I spent a lot of time in chat trying to defend it...)

Comment: @murgatroid99 For the record, though, I do think this is right, it's just hard to emphatically prove it from the rules; they don't really say anything about "can be blocked as though" meaning "while declaring blockers act as though" vs "when evaluating the legality of a set of blocks act as though" but I'm pretty confident it's the latter. The purpose of the layers stuff was to come to a conclusion even if you weren't convinced by the interpretation of the wording on the card, not to say that I think you actually need to think about layers to figure this one out.

Comment: How can you say "it's hard to prove it from the rules" when rule 613.10 gives a definitive answer? And the difference in "can be blocked as though" isn't what I was talking about. The interpretation depends on what "treat the game exactly as if the stated condition were true". Even if you're only doing it while declaring blockers, if that statement means "Evaluate continuous effects as though the stated condition were true", then without 613.10 your answer is wrong. And I'm actually pretty sure that's what it means, but 613.10 makes the interpretation not matter.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I'm not saying it's hard to get an answer at all from the rules, I'm saying it's hard to prove an answer the way I attempted to here (and the way ikegami started to).

Comment: But do you not agree that my answer is definitive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16433/discussion-between-jefromi-and-murgatroid99).

Comment: You can contrast the wording on Deadfall with Hammerheim, the latter of which actually does remove the ability, thus allowing Petroglyphs to apply.

Comment: @HaoYe If you look at the discussion in chat here, and on ikegami's answer, it's quite clear that no one thinks that the ability is removed. murgatroid's claim is rather about the scope of the "as though" - for things within that scope, one acts as though there it doesn't have forestwalk, in particular that the scope possibly includes the whole game state at the point at which "can/can't be blocked" decisions are made.

Comment: @Jefromi - my bad, tl;dr.

Answer (score 4):

Deadfall simply makes Forestwalk ineffective, so Sunweb can't block it.

---

Forestwalk is an evasion ability.

> 702.14b Landwalk is an evasion ability.

Deadfall makes it so you Forestwalkers can no longer evade. That's all Deadfall does. As CR 609.4 points out, Deadfall only applies very specifically to "determining if a creature can block".

> 609.4. Some effects state that a player may do something "as though" some condition were true or a creature can do something "as though" some condition were true. This applies only to the stated effect. For purposes of that effect, treat the game exactly as if the stated condition were true. For all other purposes, treat the game normally.

Muraganda Petroglyphs attempts to determinine if a creature has abilities. As such, The effect from Deadfall's ability is irrelevant.

It's still 1/1, and as such, Sunweb can't block it.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this is how it works, but I'm hoping to get some official reference that describes exactly what is affected by "as though it didn't have [ability]". It does seem to me that that phrase could reasonably be interpreted as saying that the side effects of not having that ability should be considered.

Comment: @murgatroid99 This is really a case of just read what it says on the cards, I think. Deadfall only applies to blocking, not anything else. If they really meant for it to cause things to *lose* forestwalk, they'd say so - there are plenty of cards that say something of the form "creatures your opponents control lose hexproof". But it doesn't - it just says "can be blocked as though they didn't have forestwalk".

Comment: I know that it doesn't make the creature lose forestwalk. I never said that. What I'm asking is whether "as though it didn't have forestwalk" means "as long as blockers are being declared, resolve continuous effects for the creature as though it didn't have forestwalk" or "it can be blocked even if you have a forest".

Comment: @murgatroid99 Well, then I don't see the issue. We both agree it has forestwalk (an ability) the entire time. You're allowed to declare blockers ("can be blocked") as though it didn't, but the card doesn't say anything beyond that.

Comment: Re "It does seem to me that that phrase could reasonably be interpreted as ...", Like I said, I understand what your saying. But as a disassociated rules expert, I say that's not the case. Even when Sunweb's disregards Forestwalk, Muraganda doesn't.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I think the main thing ikegami and I are trying to say is that "...can be blocked as though..." really, really only applies to the decision of what is a legal block and what isn't. I feel like I might've seen a ruling somewhere about that, but it's a hard thing to search for.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Oh, there's actually a comp rules clause about "as though" - see my answer.

Comment: OK, I see that. And that rule seem to say what I'm saying: that *when deciding whether blocks are legal*, treat the game exactly as if the creature didn't have forestwalk, **which includes considering that it *would* be pumped by Muraganda Petroglyphs**.

Comment: Not at all. Whether or not Muraganda pumps or not is outside of the scope of this "as though". Updated answer.

Comment: @murgatroid99 The fact that it will ultimately affect other blocking restrictions doesn't turn Muraganda's effect into a blocking decision/restriction. Its effect only does what it says on the card. For the purposes of deciding whether or not Sunweb can block, sure, you can ignore forestwalk, but that doesn't mean you get to go back and rewrite other cards' effects.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Actually, I think we can sidestep the entire issue thanks to the order in which continuous effects are applied - revised my answer. I think probably the rules were written this way to keep from getting into weird situations like this in the first place.

Comment: @ikegami I have downvoted this answer because even though the conclusion is correct, the entire reasoning is interpretation that is debatable. The ability doesn't **say** that it makes Forestwalk ineffective, and the quoted rule doesn't **say** what your last sentence says. The other answer quotes a rule that definitively answers the question.

Comment: Ah, no, that's not what I meant. The conclusion I was referring to is "Sunweb can't block it." And that's not what the ability says. The literal text of the ability is in the question. You are claiming that it **means** that Forestwalk no longer constitutes an effective blocking restriction, but that's not what the ability **says**. I think your interpretation of "as though" is incorrect, and in any case I think that depending on interpretation to resolve rules disputes is a bad strategy, especially when another rule (613.10) unambiguously answers the question.

Comment: Evasion abilities create blocking restrictions. See 509.1b. And my point is that that's not what Deadfall **says**. That's how you're interpreting Deadfall. It doesn't say "Forestwalk has no effect"; it says "as though it didn't have Forestwalk." And I disagree with both your interpretation of that statement and your interpretation of 609.4. If you want to see my previous arguments on this point, they are in the latest comments on the other answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16469/discussion-between-murgatroid99-and-ikegami).

Comment: Please don't put words in my mouth. I said that I think that evaluating that effect, and any other continuous effect, is part of the process of determining whether blockers are legal.

Comment: @murgatroid, 609.4 says that DF applies very specifically to "determining if a creature can block". It does not apply to "determining if a creature has abilities". Refined my answer further.